# How to use images stored in isolated storage for a storyboard animation?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I can't seem to get the images I have stored in isolated storage to appear in my story board, I can output the images onto the screen while I take a picture with the camera but then when I use the same filename `Value = String.Format("MyImage{0:D2}.jpg", i)` as where I stored them it doesn't seem to work should I be opening isolated storage again in the storyboard.   I am using the candle animation tutorial [here](http://compiledexperience.com/windows-phone/tutorials/candle) but these images are in a folder saved statically.  can anyone help I would appreciate it greatly thanks.

**EDIT**
I can open one Image from isolated storage but it is the last image that appears, I dont even know if it is running the animation as it's only one image, Can anyone help? *code is in second post below*

```
private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        AnimationPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        storyboard = new Storyboard
        {
            RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
        };

        var animation = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, CandleImage);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Source"));

        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);

        for (int i = 0; i <= savedCounter; i++)
        {
            var keyframe = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
            {
                KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50 * i)),
                Value = String.Format("MyImage{0:D2}.jpg", i)//images from isolated storage
            };

            animation.KeyFrames.Add(keyframe);
        }

        Resources.Add("CandleStoryboard", storyboard);

        storyboard.Begin();
    }


}
```

**EDIT**
I can open one Image from isolated storage but it is the last image that appears, I dont even know if it is running the animation as it's only one image, Can anyone help? Thanks

here is the code I am using

```
for (int i = 0; i < savedCounter; i++)
            {
                try
                {

                    image.SetSource(isStore.OpenFile("MyImage"+i+".jpg", FileMode.Open));//images from isolated storage

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    //throw;
                }


                var keyframe = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                {

                    KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50 * i)),
                    Value = image

                };

                animation.KeyFrames.Add(keyframe);
            }

            Resources.Add("CandleStoryboard", storyboard);

            storyboard.Begin();
        }
        else
        {
            storyboard.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to call the isolated storage again and stream image from that.

Comment: Never tested it, but you can try using the "isostore" uri scheme to reference your image: `isostore:/MyImage01.jpg`

Comment: Hi guys thanks for helping ,I tried using `var keyframe = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                {

                    KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50 * i)),
                    Value = isStore.OpenFile(String.Format("MyImage{0:D2}.jpg", i), FileMode.Open)//images from isolated storage
           
                };` and got "this Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream." Exception was unhandled.
How do I open multiple images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my edit above I had to move a BitmapImage inside the loop as it needs a new instance each time, took awhile to find but as is working now.

Answer (score 0):

read the image from isolatedstorage using IsolatedStorageFileStream and then use it in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try the following code,

MainPage.xaml:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Button Content="Save to IsolatedStorageSettings" Click="btnSave_Click"/>
            <Button Content="Get Data from IsolatedStorageSettings" Click="btnGet_Click"/>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="50"/>
            <Image Source="{Binding Flag}" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

</StackPanel>
```

MainPage.Xaml.cs:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SaveStringObject();
            SaveCompositeObject();
        }

private void btnGet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(settings.Contains("myemail"))
            {
                //Retrieve email Data
                var location = settings["myemail"].ToString();
                settings["email"] = "support@windowsphonnegeek.com";
            }

            //Retrieve City Data
            City City1;
            settings.TryGetValue<City>("city", out City1);

            this.DataContext = City1;
        }

public void SaveStringObject()
        {
            var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
            settings.Add("myemail", "support@windowsphonnegeek.com");
        }

        public void SaveCompositeObject()
        {
            var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
            City city = new City { Name = "London", Flag = "UK.png" };
            settings.Add("city", city);
        }

        public class City
        {
            public string Name
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string Flag
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }
```

You can Save and Get the Images from Isolated Storage. Now you can use this for animation using storyboard.

Comment: Hi my problem is opening the images in isolated storage inside the loop, I can open them and bind them to a listbox already, it's just inside this loop for the animation I can't, it only outputs the last image.
You can't bind to a storyboard either.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage(VS.95).aspx, Check this for IsolatedStorage with loop

Comment: Thanks for the link but I don't know where to use this in my loop as it returns the last file name, same as my own code?