# How to bind an image in a storyboard animation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need to bind to a Storyboard, but I cant figure how. I have the binding working on another control but cant seem to get it to work with this one. Can you help me, is this possible?

how can I have instead of this xaml

```
<Storyboard x:Key="CandleStoryboardXaml" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CandleImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.50" Value="/images/candle_01.jpg" />
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.100" Value="/images/candle_02.jpg" />
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.150" Value="/images/candle_03.jpg" />
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.200" Value="/images/candle_04.jpg" />
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.250" Value="/images/candle_05.jpg" />
    ...
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>`
```

to something like this

```
<Storyboard x:Key="CandleStoryboardXaml" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CandleImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame  Value="{Binding SourceItem}" />         
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create the first storyboard *exactly* using a binding, the answer is you can't. Collection binding in Silverlight is performed by an `ItemsControl`, which builds items based on a template and adds them to the visual tree. A storyboard does not have a visual tree, so you cannot use this approach in this context.

I would suggest writing some code to create your storyboard based on your array of images. If you are concerned about having code-behind, you could always package the code as an attached behaviour.

Comment: Hi Colin well I have been trying that and came into another snag I have another question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923067/how-to-use-images-stored-in-isolated-storage-for-a-storyboard-animation) and I can get the images to bind to a listbox, but when I use isolated storage to get the images to iterate in the story board it does not work for me. I don't know how to open multiple images in isolated storage.

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a stack panel and add the images one by one in horizontal or vertical way.

```
            <StackPanel.Resources>

            <EventTrigger x:Name="event" RoutedEvent="StackPanel.Loaded">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>

            <BeginStoryboard>

            <Storyboard x:Name="mystoryboard">

          <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
           Storyboard.TargetName="Trans" 
           Storyboard.TargetProperty="X">
         <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="-387" KeyTime="0:0:1" />




         </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>


  <Image Height="165" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="400,40,-400,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" Source="{Binding SourceItem}">
                                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="Trans" X="0" Y="0" />
                                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                                </Image>
```